# How can I know if I received a message from a topic or a Sender ID?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With Firebase Cloud Messaging, I'm receiving messages from topics and Sender ID. However, I need to know if the message comes from a topic or a sender id.

There is the `RemoteMessage.getFrom()` method to know the sender, I could try to determine if it's a topic or a sender id by checking the length if sender id if it's always the same size. Or I could just add a prefix to all my topics, but that's only a workaround.

What's the right way to do that?

Comment: Scratch that. Guess it's possible with `getFrom()`, basing from the docs. One way you could do is add a custom parameter as an identifier in your payload.

Comment: Okay so there is no 'official' way to do it... Thanks anyway!

Comment: RemoteMessage.getFrom() returns somethings like "/topics/..." if it's a topic. So no need to add any extra parameter. We just need to do  remoteMessage.getFrom().startsWith("/topics/") to check if it comes from a topic.